# Как в VS Code перейти в класс или переменную?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code

в phpStorm или rubyMine например зажимаешь ctrl и жмёшь на класс или переменную автоматически переходит к ней, а как в vs code такое сделать?

Comment: Клавиша `alt`..